# Update query with NULL values

Tags: sql

This is the query i want to execute but it shows an error:

> unexpected token near NULL and unrecognized keyword.

What do I do?

```
UPDATE scidr_tbllicense 
SET SPLD_DeviceID_Mfg = 'rachana', 
    SPLD_DeviceID_ModelNo = 'yuu',
    SPLD_DeviceID_SrNo = '34',
    SPLD_DeviceID_Search_mode = '1',
    SPLD_LicenseType = NULL,
    SPLD_LicenseTypeChangedDate = NULL,
    SPLD_LicenseActiveStatus = NULL 
WHERE SPLD_DeviceID_Mfg = 'rachana' AND 
      SPLD_DeviceID_ModelNo ='yuu' AND 
      SPLD_DeviceID_SrNo = '34'
```

Comment: Can you show us the marked up version of the full string, because I think there is a ' missing at the end and "" around the string.

Comment: sorry i missed a ' at the end

Comment: Please post the design of scidr_tbllicense

Comment: What RDMS are your working with? SQL Server? Postgre? Oracle? Please tag it in question.